# web app link to view any files within drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have written this script to search drive for files owned by a specific user- It works great except this function, returns all the results and the links are set to open like a doc. so pdf's and other files I am getting an error opening because the URL is wrong. Are there any generic ways to open files, or do I need to write if statements? Any possible ideas on how to get around this? Thanks

```js
    function handleResults(results){
         console.log('Handle Results was called! ');
         document.writeln('<a href="https://script.google.com/a/macros/35634534534534534534534534534">BACK</a><br/><br/>');
         var length=results.length; // total elements of results
         for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
         {
         var item=results[i];
         item=item.split("|~|"); // split the line |~|, position 0 has the filename and 1 the file id
         
         document.writeln("<b><a href='https://docs.google.com/document/d/"+item[1]+"' target='_blank'>"+item[0]+"</b></a> (Last modified: "+item[2]+")<br/><br/>"); // write result
        
        }
        document.writeln("End of results...");
       }
```

Comment: Did you try `File.getUrl()`? The documentation for the API is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @spiderPig for the use of File.getUrl();

```js
function handleResults(results){
         console.log('Handle Results was called! ');
         document.writeln('<a href="https://script.google.com/a/macros/35634534534534534534534534534">BACK</a><br/><br/>');
         var length=results.length; // total elements of results
         for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
         {
         var item=results[i];
         item=item.split("|~|"); // split the line |~|, position 0 has the filename and 1 the file URL
         // i changed item1 to contain the file.getUrl instead of the fileId
         document.writeln("<b><a href='"+item[1]+"' target='_blank'>"+item[0]+"</b></a> (Last modified: "+item[2]+")<br/><br/>"); // write result
        
        }
        document.writeln("End of results...");
       }
```